# How to create a conditional variable based on rules?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, panel-data

I have a time-series panel dataset that is structured in the following way: There are multiple funds that each own multiple stocks and we have the time series of the weight of the stock within that portfolio and the total value of the portfolio for that year. As you can see the panel is not balanced.

```
df <- data.frame(
  fund_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  stock_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  year = c(2011L, 2012L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L,2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L),
  weight = c(0.3L, 0.2L, 0.7L, 0.8L, 1L, 0.2L, 0.1L, 0.2L, 0.7L, 0.8L, 0.8L, 0.2L, 0.3L, 1L, 0.5L, 0.2L, 0.7L),
 aum = c(3L, 3.5L, 3L, 3.5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L)
)
> df
   fund_id stock_id year weight aum
1        1        1 2011    0.3 3.0
2        1        1 2012    0.2 3.5
3        1        2 2011    0.7 3.0
4        1        2 2012    0.8 3.5
5        1        2 2013    1.0 4.0
6        2        1 2011    0.2 5.0
7        2        1 2012    0.1 4.0
8        2        1 2013    0.2 5.0
9        2        2 2012    0.7 4.0
10       2        2 2013    0.8 5.0
11       2        3 2011    0.8 5.0
12       2        3 2012    0.2 4.0
13       3        2 2013    0.3 6.0
14       3        2 2014    1.0 7.0
15       3        3 2011    0.5 5.0
16       3        3 2012    0.2 6.0
17       3        3 2013    0.7 6.0
>
```

I would like to assign the value of zero to weight column if the stock was present in the fund in the past 3 years and then all of sudden it's not. e.g. if stock "1" was part of fund "1" portfolio in 2011 and 2012 then as long as there is a positive weight for that stock in the past 3 years I would like to have a new row to be created for stock "1" in year 2013 with the weight value of zero and the correct fund aum (Value) of 4.

I think the rule should start by grouping by the fund and then looking at the max year within the fund and then creating the missing year rows for every stock up the max year. Then update the value of newly created rows' weight based on the fact that stock was present in the past 3 years or not if true assign zero value to the weight if not delete the row. So for example, if the stock was present only in 4 years before, then we do not want to have that stock for that year at all so that row should be deleted.

Comment: Since It's been a few days since I  posted this question, is there a place where you guys suggest I start with?

Comment: Can you explain more about calculating the "correct fund aum" across fund_ids/stock_ids?

Comment: What I mean by correct fund aum is the aum for that particular year and fund. As the aum is only fund-specific and doesn't change across stock holdings. So for example if we create a zero column for stock 1 for year 2014 for fund 2 then I would like to have the fund 2, 2014 aum also included as a column with the newly created row. honestly, this is pretty easy to do at the end so doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

It was unclear to me how to replace missing weight/aum values for combinations other than stock_id=1/fund_id=1. This could be a potential place to start.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  fund_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  stock_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  year = c(2011L, 2012L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L,2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L),
  weight = c(0.3L, 0.2L, 0.7L, 0.8L, 1L, 0.2L, 0.1L, 0.2L, 0.7L, 0.8L, 0.8L, 0.2L, 0.3L, 1L, 0.5L, 0.2L, 0.7L),
  aum = c(3L, 3.5L, 3L, 3.5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L)
)

df <- df %>%
  # make data wide
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(1:2),
    names_from = year, values_from = c(aum, weight)) 

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(fund_id, stock_id) %>%
  # If weight was NOT NA in 2011 and 2012, but NA for 2013,then give weight 0 for 2013
  mutate(weight_2013_v2 = if_else ( ( ( !is.na(weight_2011)) & (!is.na(weight_2012)) & 
                                     is.na(weight_2013)), 0, weight_2013)) %>%
  # If weight was NOT NA in 2012 and 2013, but NA for 2014,then give weight 0 for 2014
  mutate(weight_2014_v2 = if_else ( ( ( !is.na(weight_2012)) & (!is.na(weight_2013)) & 
                                     is.na(weight_2014)), 0, weight_2014)) %>%
  # If weight was NOT NA in 2011 and 2012, but NA for 2013,then give aum 4 for 2013 (?)
  mutate(aum_2013_v2 = if_else ( ( ( !is.na(weight_2011)) & (!is.na(weight_2012)) & 
                                     is.na(weight_2013)), 4, aum_2013)) %>%
  # If weight was NOT NA in 2012 and 2013, but NA for 2014,then give aum 4 for 2014 (?)
  mutate(aum_2014_v2 = if_else ( ( ( !is.na(weight_2012)) & (!is.na(weight_2013)) & 
                                     is.na(weight_2014)), 4, aum_2014)) %>%
  # clean up
  select(-c(weight_2013, weight_2014, aum_2013, aum_2014)) %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(., '_v2'))
  
df3 <- df2 %>%
  # make long
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("20"), 
               names_to = "year", values_to = "value", 
               values_drop_na = FALSE, names_repair = "minimal") %>%
  separate(col = year, into = c("type", "year"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -c(type), names_from = type, values_from = value)

# delete a row if it contains na
df4 <- drop_na(df3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response but my actual dataset is massive with more than 240 periods so I was looking for a functional solution that would be scalable.